# Django how to set initial object to ModelList?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've created a simple model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

and a simple ModelForm

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Person
```

how can I put a Person object that I already have (e.g. `Person.objects.get(pk=1)`) to become an initial value for the form? I need to edit this object

Comment: You just need to bind the form to the instance or copy of the object you need to show as initial value (eg: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). Just make sure you create a new instance of the object, while saving, and not end up editing the saved instance. You can use javascript to reset the values of the form inputs on hover, so that the user does not have to delete the preset values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs:

```
# Creating a form to add an article.
>>> form = ArticleForm()

# Creating a form to change an existing article.
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

so in your case, in your views.py:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
form = PersonForm(instance=person)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform